# Enable proximity sensor in background

Tags: ios, background, voip, proximity

I'm developing a VoIP App. I want to use the proximity sensor just like the native call. I enale the proximity sensor when a call come. It work fine when the call is in foreground; But when I put it to background, it seems the proximity sensor can't work. Is anything I can do to improve this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem with proximity sensors disable in background of the app. Are you able to fix this.? If yes. PLease let me know

Comment: I am trying to build something similar. Do you have some updates on this?

Comment: i also need same solution . i tried much much even apple document as well but find nothing , so please if any solution found regarding this then please let me know about that.